# LinearLayout not work with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create following layout.

```
--------------------------------



 Title
 Summary                   Info

[Get Direction][Call][More Info]
--------------------------------
```

I code following layout but buttons not showing. I have no idea why LinearLayout works like FrameLayout so the RelativeLayout hides buttons. Did I miss something here?
I am using support library 22.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/location_card_height">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/cardImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Title" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/title">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/info"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:hint="Info"

                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end" />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/summary"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:hint="Summary"

                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/info"
                    android:ellipsize="end"  />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelAction"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDirection"
                android:text="@string/get_direction"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCall"
                android:text="@string/label_call"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMoreInfo"
                android:text="@string/more_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You want Above Layout only? Or you want to do this in FrameLayout only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relative layout has been set to match_parent for it height!

change it to wrap_content
that should help you

or put it in a LinearLayout
something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/location_card_height">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/cardImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom" >

                <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:hint="Title" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/title">

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/info"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:hint="Info"

                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:ellipsize="end" />

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/summary"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:hint="Summary"

                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/info"
                        android:ellipsize="end"  />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelAction"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDirection"
                android:text="@string/get_direction"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCall"
                android:text="@string/label_call"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMoreInfo"
                android:text="@string/more_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine With Linearlayout Then Here is Your XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cardImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/info"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:hint="Summary"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Summary"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:hint="Info"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance" />
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/panelAction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDirection"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Get_direction" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="call" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMoreInfo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="more_info" />
</LinearLayout>
```